# Getting image from contour and mask

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm getting an image from classification and it's mask using Mask RCNN.

Now I'm getting the following image
[image]

I would like to get the area around the contour as an image without the background.

```
 //Display the label at the top of the bounding box
    int baseLine;
    Size labelSize = getTextSize(label, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1, &baseLine);
    box.y = max(box.y, labelSize.height);
    //rectangle(frame, Point(box.x, box.y - round(1.5 * labelSize.height)), Point(box.x + round(1.5 * labelSize.width), box.y + baseLine), Scalar(255, 255, 255), FILLED);
    //putText(frame, label, Point(box.x, box.y), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1);

    // Resize the mask, threshold, color and apply it on the image

    Scalar color = colors[classId % colors.size()];

    // Resize the mask, threshold, color and apply it on the image
    resize(objectMask, objectMask, Size(box.width, box.height));
    Mat mask = (objectMask > maskThreshold);
    Mat coloredRoi = (0.3 * color + 0.7 * frame(box));
    coloredRoi.convertTo(coloredRoi, CV_8UC3);

    // Draw the contours on the image
    vector<Mat> contours;
    Mat hierarchy;
    mask.convertTo(mask, CV_8U);
    findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy, RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    drawContours(coloredRoi, contours, -1, color, 5, LINE_8, hierarchy, 100);
    coloredRoi.copyTo(frame(box), mask);


    imshow("img", coloredRoi);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

this is the image showing of just the mask:

[image]

source image:

[image]

Comment: combine the mask and the source picture: set to 0 all pixels where `~mask`. I won't bother looking for previous questions like this because this is too basic.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz If you're looking for something challenging you can check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594896/segmenting-cow-pigs-leg-using-pcl

Comment: Can you share the source image so we may try your code with that image

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I shared the source image, thanks for your concern